# How to setup a relationship so that more than one type of object can be in a set with Spring Roo

Tags: java, inheritance, entity-relationship, spring-roo

My domain thus far looks like:

```
~.domain.RenderJob
~.domain.RenderLayer
~.domain.ImageLayer extends ~.domain.RenderLayer
~.domain.ColorLayer extends ~.domain.RenderLayer
```

I'd like to add a set field to RenderJob named 'layers'. Elements in the set can be either of type ImageLayer or ColorLayer, both of which extend RenderLayer. Is there a way to set up the layers field so that it will accept either of the two types of layers?

Answer (score 0):

well I think this will work for you

```
field set --fieldName layers --element ~.domain.RenderLayer --class ~.domain.RenderJob
```

Thanks

Shekhar